# Declaring Javascript function wihout definition(body)

Tags: javascript, function, declaration, definition

I am new to javascript and I want to know that is there a way to declare a function without defining it. As we do in **C**:

```
int sum(int, int);
```

and then we can write it's definition later. As in:

```
int sum(int A, intB){
    return A+B;
}
```

Do we have a way in javascript to just declare a function without defining it?

Comment: No. Functions are hoisted to the top of the scope, so they are defined before anything else, regardless of where they actually are in the code. Hence, you can use a function anywhere in your code, regardless of where the function is actually defined.

Comment: The reason you need to do that in C is so the compiler can perform proper type checking. You shouldn't need to worry about this since JavaScript is interpreted. Are you running into a specific problem?

Comment: I need it so that my code passes through JSLint successfully.